# Redirecting in react-router-dom v6 in a non-JSX context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tauri

I'm trying to redirect a user from the route they are currently looking at to another route programatically. In my case, I am **not** in a JSX environment, and cannot use any kind of React hooks. How would I go about this?

I tried to use the code block below to redirect (tried using JSX), only to realize that it wouldn't work as it isn't in the context of the root router.

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>
    <Navigate to="/" />
</div>, document.getElementById("redirect"));
```

I also want to try and redirect without using `window.location.href =` as that would cause the whole page to refresh, something I don't want to happen.

EDIT: As requested, I am trying to redirect to a page from an event that is emitted by *Tauri* and is handled by some TypeScript code on the front end. Using `window.location.href` isn't an issue in any case.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
/**
 * Sets up event listeners.
 */
export async function setupListeners() {
    console.log("Setting up link event listeners...");
    await listen("deeplink", onLinked);
}
 
/**
 * Invoked when a deep link call is received.
 * @param event The event.
 */
async function onLinked(event: Event<string>) {
    const { payload } = event;
    if (payload == "test:")
        // redirect("/testPage");
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to share where you ***are*** trying to redirect from, and where that code is in relation to the React app code? Is there a problem using `window.location.href` to redirect into your React app *other than* you don't like/want a page refresh?

Comment: Went ahead and added the requested details as well as an example.

Comment: Why can't `setupListeners` be called in the context of react?

Comment: You might try using [window.history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Answer (score 0):

See [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect):

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const loader = async () => {
  const user = await getUser();
  if (!user) {
    return redirect("/login");
  }
};
```

(from the docs)

Comment: OP clearly said they are not in any React/JSX context. Using a RRD data router loader function is in the React code.